# Помогите сделать поиск/фильтр данных на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, filter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это верстка моей формы. Пользователь должен вводить данные чтобы получить максимально похожие отфильтрованные места. сначала отфильтрованные данные "откуда", потом "куда" и по дате.

Пока что нет готовых POST данных, по которым я бы могла искать...
Пожалуйста помогите реализовать это. Ниже код HTML

```
введите сюда код
   <div class="input-box">
      <small>Места выезда и прибытия</small> 
     <input type="text" class="from-input" placeholder="Откуда">
     <input type="text" class="to-input" placeholder="Куда">
     <span>Дата и время</span>
     <input type="datetime-local" name="" id="" class="datetime">
     <button type="submit" class="button">Поиск</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из представленной формы могу предположить что поиск осуществляется по нажатию соответствующей кнопки, тогда Вам надо на нее добавить обработчик клика

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [onclick](https://webref.ru/html/attr/onclick)

В данном обработчике, необходимо получить введенные пользователем значения, например можно получить через

- [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)(`селектор`).value.

Затем при помощи последовательного вызова [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) для каждого введенного пользователем значения получаете нужный Вам список.